# Disabling Audio on Internal Speakers for High Sierra onwards?

Tags: high-sierra, audio, headphones

I have users in my lab that run sound via their speakers.  I would like to disable the ability to do so on all machines in the lab to prevent this, whilst still allowing them to use their headphones.

I have read articles about how to disable all audio (not a totally desirable outcome, but better than the alternative) by deleting the IOAudioFamily.kext file, however, this doesn't seem to work on High Sierra.

Has anyone aware of a solution to this issue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: sudo osascript -e "set Volume 0"

Answer (score 1):

I found this for you...

How to set the volume level to the secret minimum

So here's the deal, normally when you set the volume to 0 the speakers are automatically muted. On the keyboard you can hit the mute button while the volume is at 0 and it will unmute to the secret lowest volume setting.

Likewise, you can instruct AppleScript to not automatically mute the volume:

```
osascript -e "set volume without output muted output volume 1 --100%"
```

How to set the volume without unmuting

Sometimes you want the volume to stay muted, but to come on at a particular level when you unmute.

This is how you prevent the audio from unmuting when you adjust the volume level:

```
osascript -e "set volume with output muted output volume 42 --100%"
```

Comment: If it works for you check the answer so others can find it.

Comment: Will do, just want to test the outcomes first.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of software-based solutions, but most of them do not support multi-device control, which is what you're looking for. So, whether you disable computer audio completely, or limit the volume on all devices, it sounds like it's not entirely what you're looking for.

> I would like to disable the ability to do so on all machines in the lab to prevent this, whilst still allowing them to use their headphones.

One simple approach to this would be to purchase a [short headphone extension cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CNAUYBY) for each computer. With this extension cable plugged in, all audio will be routed to the headphones even though there may not be any headphones plugged in to the built-in jack. I think that would be simplest, provided no one removes it from the back of the computer.

Among the other software-based approaches, such as [Earsafe](https://earsafe.io), [Whisper](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/whisper-volume-limiter/id1438132944), or [Volimeter (CLI)](https://gist.github.com/atr000/223401), and [Volume Limiter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/volume-limiter/id1478846233?mt=12) only Volume Limiter gives the ability to do this on a per-device basis.